# HMAC SHA256 - Php To Python

Tags: python, php

PHP CODE SNIPPET

```
$timestamp    = time();
$appID        = 1;
$key          = '5nF6Ai4ykPY=';
$secret       = '0a75...';

$sign = "key:".$key."id:".$appID.":timestamp:".$timestamp;
$authtoken = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $secret, true)));  
echo $authtoken;
echo $timestamp;
```

got an encoded string with the value:

`wlhiAYAxcUsH1eOx66cJwg8G1ROAbagEqVBo6msBNF8%3D`

PYTHON CODE SNIPPET

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

timestamp = time.time()
appid = 60
key = "scas11eABXs="
secret = "N4Rlq....=="

sign = f"key:{key}id:{appid}:timestamp:{int(timestamp)}"


signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), sign.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

got this value

`8a85743f3b1704096b3fe5018de2ff133eb2bac63c93fa8ff26cca328ab83e39`

The value i got from the python is way too different from the php, i mean it almost like hexadecimal where as the value from the php code is something different.

Can anyone please help and convert this php code snippet to python so i can get almost similar values.

Comment: So your timestamps are different, appID's are different, Key and secret are different and you get a different answer? Try setting them all to a fixed values before comparing the two

Comment: You are also using `rawurlencode` which will encode into a URL where it appears the python version might be doing a `bin2hex()` in the PHP world

Comment: All this to say is you are comparing apples to Spaghettios. They both are round but that's where the similarities end. You should be using fixed data points before performing the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

These two are the exact same between Python and PHP. The key part to observe is that in Python the `hexdigest()` can be translated to `bin2hex()` in PHP.

Below I set the same values for the timestamp, appid, key, and secret. When the timestamp changes so will the underlying values. You should always use fixed data that will not change (encryption keys, ephemeral data, etc) when comparing algorithms.

Python

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
import time

timestamp = int(1617543014)
appid = 60
key = "scas11eABXs="
secret = "N4Rlq=="

sign = "key:" + key +"id:" + str(appid) + ":timestamp:" + str(timestamp)

signature = hmac.new(secret.encode(), sign.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

PHP

```php
<?php
$timestamp    = 1617543014;
$appID        = 60;
$key          = 'scas11eABXs=';
$secret       = 'N4Rlq==';

$sign = "key:".$key."id:".$appID.":timestamp:".$timestamp;
$authtoken = bin2hex(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $secret, true));
echo $authtoken;
```

Both produce:

```
de409427af722c4cfbcb7bd280cd33ace71f33d29d4fc54182ce2a3ee758712e
```